# Are TextBox.BorderStyle = FixedSingle or Fixed3D deprecated?

Tags: winforms, textbox, controls

I use 2 Textboxes in a Windows Form using Visual Studio 2019.

For first TextBox, `BorderStyle` is set to `FixedSingle` and for second, `BorderStyle` is set to `Fixed3D`.

I obtain following display

[image]

Apart left margin, I don't see any difference !

Question: What is difference between `FixedSingle` and `Fixed3D` ?

Since, I don't see any 3D effect, is Fixed3D deprecated ?

Is there another properties or parameters to assign for TextBox or Form to see 3D effects ?

Comment: They seem to have different values, from  [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/BorderStyle.cs,f3a9eae9f52ae85b,references) documentation. So not sure why it has no effect

Comment: Have you tried with commenting out Application.EnableVisualStyles() ?

Comment: There is 1 pixel difference (all sides) in the internal padding. Then the final rendering depends on the VisualStyles, applied based on the System settings. In Windows 10, it's rendered like that. In Windows 7, you'd see a shadowed (light-gray) internal border. `CreateParams` sets the same ExStyle and Style in both .Net Frameworks and .Net Core / .Net 5

Comment: @Guido: calling EnableVisualStyle works as I want ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On `Visual Studio 2022` and `Windows 11` using `.Net6.0` WinForm application, this difference doesn't exist anymore !

[image]

when `3D` TextBox has focus

[image]

Using `EnableVisualStyles()` is not more necessary (for TextBox) !